# SQLite how to get average values of available offers in a time frame

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry for the title, because it's all but self-explanatory.

So I have a database which is daily populated with used car offers, each one having as columns: `price`, `in_date` (day when an offer was registered) and `exit_date` (day when an offer ceases to exist, defaulting to 'Null' otherwise). Note that no longer available offers stay on the database, with their corresponding 'exit_date'.

**What I need:**

I'd like to `SELECT` the average price of offers available on each possible 'in_date' existing in the database:

```
in_date     |  avg price
-------------------------
2018-05-27  |  8157
2018-05-29  |  8240
2018-06-01  |  8199
2018-06-02  |  8220
```

The problem is that I need to compare `in_date` for each row with `in_date` and `exit_date` in the rest of the rows, and I have no clue how to do that.

Trying to express this into some code:

```
SELECT
    in_date**,
    (SELECT avg(price) FROM offers WHERE in_date** > in_date and exit_date > in_date** or exit_date is null)
from oferted
GROUP by in_date**
```

`in_date**` being a 'fixed' `in_date` value for each row to compare the `in_date` and `exit_date` of the rest of the rows to.

thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue with the `exit_date`, partly because you did not include data for that column.  Please show us a minimal sample data which explains what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close.  You can do this using a subquery in the `from` to get the in dates -- and then qualify the column names:

```
SELECT d.in_date,
    (SELECT avg(o.price)
     FROM offers o
     WHERE d.in_date > o.in_date and
           (o.exit_date > d.in_date or exit_date is null)
   )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT in_date 
      FROM offsets
     ) d;
```